# scope of local variable in enum constant

Tags: java, enums

I make a local variable inside the block of enum constant like:

```
enum NUMBER {
    ONE() {
        int one = 1;
    },
    TWO() {
        int two = ONE.one + 1; //!ERROR: one can't be resolved.
    }
}
```

My question is why I can not refer to other constant's class field variable?

Is it a class field?

What I know is, ONE and TWO are field of NUMBER, so ONE can see TWO and access TWO's field, isn't it?

Comment: Because you are defining an anonymous sub class (sub enum). All we know about `ONE` is that it is a `NUMBER` and `NUMBER` does not have a `one` field.

Comment: However, you can still declare fields in your `NUMBER` `enum` and initialize it when declaring your constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An anonymous inner class is a full-fledged object and thus can define
>   fields and methods for its internal use.  These fields and methods,
>   unless they override a method of the superclass, are not visible to
>   the outside world because an anonymous inner class is always typed to
>   its superclass, which doesn't have those methods or fields.   But it
>   can be very useful to the operation of the anonymous inner class to
>   have those fields and methods, so use them if you need them.

[Reference](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/JavaResources/anon_inner.html)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because when you declare it as

```
ONE () {
}
```

you're declaring a new anonymous inner class.

You can, however, declare a field in your `NUMBER` enum, add it to `NUMBER` constructor and then declare it in your constants as such:

```
ONE(1), TWO(2)
```

because enums are like regular classes and allow such a declaration.